# Any Way 'Do' When Near a Number in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

My question is that for example when i write code for number of 106. 106 is " value of a". And for "value of b" program will do this calculation near of 106 number. Like; 104,105,107,108 etc.

I want to do this with while command.

Like;

Do While b near the a.

Comment: not built-in... but you could write something using a `Select Case` or a mathematical algorithm using `Cint` and multiplication.

Comment: `For b = a-2 To a+2`